# JavaScript push object into array changed value of object

Tags: javascript, arrays, angularjs, object

I am not sure what the keyword I should use to google my problem. But I have been banging my head on the wall for three hours trying to see what is wrong here. It is just a simple pushing object into array. The problem is, when I tried to `console.log` the array value, two of the `object` keys' value were changed. I am writing this in an AngularJS controller.

Here is the sample object which I put on a service:

```
onbd.data.add = {
    predefined: [{
        activity : 'morning jog',
        purpose  : 'grow',
        days     : '0 1 2 3 4 5 6',
        start    : '05:30',
        stop     : '06:00',
        meta     : 'repeats everyday on 5:30 AM for half an hour'
    }]
};
```

In controller, here is the function that got called on `ng-click` event, which will push the said data from service into the AJAX data array:

```
th.setActivity = function (data) {
    // the data is one of the object inside the predefined
    // key from the service above
    var newAct = {
        activity : data.activity,
        purpose  : data.purpose,
        day      : data.days,
        start    : data.start,
        stop     : data.stop
    };
    th.list.push(newAct);
};
```

Here is what I got from `console.log('newAct', newAct)`:

```
newAct Object {
    activity: "morning jog",
    purpose: "grow",
    day: "0 1 2 3 4 5 6",
    start: "05:30",
    stop: "06:00"
```

}

Which is correct, but here is what I got when I `console.log('list', th.list);`:

```
list [Object]
    0: Object
        $$hashKey: "object:136"
        activity: "morning jog"
        day: "0 1 2 3 4 5 6"
        purpose: "grow"
        start: "05:30"
        stop: "06:00"
    length: 1
    __proto__: Array[0]
```

Notice that the key `day` and `purpose` has changed. This happens only when I execute that `th.setActivity` function. Any thoughts why such a bizarre behavior?

Thank you very much.

Comment: Objects are passed by reference, and the console (in chrome) will try to be helpful and keep that reference up to date. Are these values being modified somewhere else?

Comment: No, they are not being modified. I have another similar function which will handle data input from `form` rather than predefined data on the service. But that one works without any problem.

Comment: Since you get data through `ajax`, which is async, I guess you need [`$scope.$apply`](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/type/$rootScope.Scope#$apply).

Comment: Can you check console.log('newAct', newAct) before th.list.push(newAct); line

Comment: @Joy I think you misunderstood, I don't use AJAX to provide the predefined data, it was hardcoded on the service to share between controllers. But this data will later be `POST`ed via AJAX, which is where I got the error on server side because of the key's value changed.

Comment: @humanoid Oh, sorry. I would suggest putting the code online to JSFiddle/Plunker/Codepen. It would be easier for others to help.

Comment: @AlaksandarJesusGene here is the log `newAct Object {activity: "morning jog", purpose: "grow", day: "0 1 2 3 4 5 6", start: "05:30", stop: "06:00"}`

Comment: @Joy I see, I will try your suggestion and update it in the question soon. Thanks! :)

Comment: figured out what was wrong, posted it in an answer. thanks guys :)

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out, thanks for @tymeJV for pointing out about the fact that the console is trying to keep the object reference up to date. I decided to `console.log()` one by one and found the problem. @tymeJV was correct that the different in value was the result of some other functions modifying the object.

My mistake was, the modifying functions expect to receive an `object` as the value instead of `string` like what I stated on the service. I have updated it and now it works.

Silly me, I know :)